# How to parse HTML table with rows contaning both <th> and <td> tags under the <tr> tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't seem to find an answer to this so I'm stumped. I'm parsing a HTML table using Beautifulsoup and table that starts with a row label `<th>` then followed by the data `<td>`. I'm parsing the data then writing it to a CSV file, I'm having trouble including the "row header" for each row which starts with the `<th>` tag.

This is what I got so far, and it get most of the job done except for the `<th>` row label `<th>`:

```
headers = [header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th',{'scope' :'col'})]

rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8').rstrip() for val in row.find_all('td')])
with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Is there a way to append that to the `rows` as well? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `find_all` can take a list, so you could try `['td', 'th']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeautifulSoup `find_all` function can take a list, so to get the `th` you can modify your script as follows:

```
headers = [header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th',{'scope' :'col'})]
rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8').rstrip() for val in row.find_all(['td', 'th'])])

with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [HTML Parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) module?

Comment: I found a way to solve it with the slight modification to the code Martin Evans suggested, but I'm curious, do you find HTML Parser to be superior to BeautifulSoup?